# Triangulating a graph of nCr, r=3?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

Given (non-repeating, order does not matter) combinations nCr, where r=3, and n is [dozens...hundreds]:

- Is it always possible to construct a planar 2D graph of connected triangles on a uniform grid, such that each triple is used exactly once?
- If so, how would you describe an algorithm for constructing this graph?  When n is hundreds, the set of combinations can become dozens of millions large, so ideally the set is iterated once (lexicographically), without maintaining an entire tree. Also, ideally the graph would fit into a minimal rectangular area.

Example for small n=6, full set of 20 combinations =

```
    1 2 3, 1 2 4, 1 2 5, 1 2 6, 1 3 4, 1 3 5, 1 3 6, 1 4 5, 1 4 6, 1 5 6,
    2 3 4, 2 3 5, 2 3 6, 2 4 5, 2 4 6, 2 5 6,
    3 4 5, 3 4 6, 3 5 6,
    4 5 6
```

Placing the first triple into the center of a 6x6 uniform grid:

```
    . . . . . .
    . . . . . .
    . . 3 . . .
    . . 1 2 . .
    . . . . . .
    . . . . . .
```

Staggering the grid to more easily visualize the triangle connectivity:

```
     . . . . . .
    . . . . . .
     . . 3 . . .
    . . 1 2 . .
     . . . . . .
    . . . . . .
```

Manually placing the full set, using each triple once (multiple possible solutions):

```
     . 6 5 . . .
    . . 4 1 5 .
     4 5 3 6 . .
    6 2 1 2 5 .
     . 6 4 3 6 .
    . . 3 . . .
```

Any pointers towards existing algorithms, or relevant terminology I can search would be appreciated, thanks.
Real-world applications are in image processing, color interpolation, palette dithering.

Comment: This shares some similarities with a [de Bruijn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) of order $3$ over an alphabet of size $n$, with two big differences: the de Bruijn sequence is only $1$-dimensional, and it contains all $n^3$ ordered triples rather than all $\binom n3$ combinations.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want. By triplets you mean three element subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$? What do you mean by "such that each triplet is used exactly once"? Would you consider something like this http://petzel.at/graph.jpg as valid?

Comment: @Lazy Here is a rigorous description. Let $H$ denote the infinite hexagonal grid. Find a way to label a connected subset of $H$ with the numbers $1$ to $n$ so that for every size-$3$ subset $\{a,b,c\}$ of $\{1,...,n\}$, there exists exactly one triangle of three mutually adjacent hexagons in $H$ which are labeled $a,b,c$ in some order. Your example is not valid since your labels are not on the infinite hexagonal grid, they're just on some arbitrary graph.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Where do you get this from? The question stated nothing about a hexagonal grid. The example was placed on a grid (actually not a hexagonal one), but the question talks simply about planar graphs. This is the reason why I am asking for what he wants. Part of asking a good question should be specifying what you want.

Comment: @MishaLavrov  Interesting.  Yes... similar to a de Bruijn torus, except constrained to the 2D plane without wraparound, and critically, 3-element triangles instead of m-by-n matrices.

Comment: @Lazy  Yes, by "triple" I mean a three element combination.  Yes, we can assume that whatever n is, it maps to the set of integers [1..n].  The linked graph is not valid, as it doesn't use every combination, e.g. [1 2 4] is missing.  However, the traversal idea is interesting, thank you.  On a uniform grid it would be sparsely connected hexagons.

Comment: @MikeEarnest  Thank you for the better description!  I edited the question to make it clear I want to place triangles on a uniform grid.  Square and hexagonal grids are interchangeable, although I find hexagonal easier to visualize.